# No identifier specified for entity for native-image app

Tags: hibernate, micronaut, graalvm-native-image, micronaut-data

I have entity with field `id` annotated by `@Id`:

```
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

@Entity
@Table(name = "orders")
@Data
@SuperBuilder
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private Long id;
}
```

Everything works properly when I run application with `mvn mn:run`.
But if build app with `mvn package -Dpackaging=native-image` and then run built app I've received an error:

`org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: Order`

micronaut version: 2.3.4, micronaut data version: 2.2.4

Comment: Having the same problem using Micronaut 3.0.1 & Micronaut Data 3.0.1. Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: Not yet........

Comment: two years later and i am facing the same issue. any update?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when building my Application as a *Native-image*.

I **solved** this doing **two** things:

1. Making the `id` field **public** (and not `private`)

> ```
> @Id
> public Long id;
> ```

2. Adding to the ***pom.xml*** the ***Annotation Processor*** for the GraalVM to build Native-image with reflection (as specified in [Micronaut Docs](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/#graal))

   - So add this to *pom.xml*

> ```
>  <annotationProcessorPaths> 
>   ...
>     <path>
>       <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
>       <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
>       <version>3.7.4</version>
>     </path>
>   ... 
>  </annotationProcessorPaths>
> ```

NOTE:

- Be sure that is not missing the `@Id` annotation on id field
- Be sure that the `@Id` annotation is imported with:

> ```
> import javax.persistence.Id;
> ```

Answer (score 0):

try to add path to the pom.xml

```
<path>
   <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
   <artifactId>micronaut-graal</artifactId>
   <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
</path>
```

when adding lombok